# Extract A record and query time from dig output

Tags: text-processing, ip-address, dig

I am having the following output when executing a dig command :

```
dig @1.1.1.1 google.com  +noall +answer +stats

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P1 <<>> @1.1.1.1 google.com +noall +answer +stats
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
obodrm.prod.at.dmdsdp.com. 86154 IN     A       62.178.85.125
;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 11 15:04:35 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

I want to filter out and display on a line the following "62.178.85.125" and Query time: 1 msec.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty trivial with awk, the exact matching conditions may be tweaked based on the possible patterns that may appear:

```
dig @1.1.1.1 google.com  +noall +answer +stats | \
  awk '$3 == "IN" && $4 == "A"{ip=$5}/Query time:/{t=$4 " " $5}END{print ip, t}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep,

```
dig @1.1.1.1 google.com  +noall +answer +stats | grep -oEe "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$" -oEe 'Query time: [0-9]+ msec'
```

- `-oEe "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$"` will grep an IP address at the end of any line
- `-oEe 'Query time: [0-9]+ msec'` to grep the qurey time.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
dig @1.1.1.1 google.com  +noall +answer +stats | \
  sed -nEz 's/.*[[:space:]]([0-9.]+)\n;; (Query time[^\n]*\n).*/\1 \2/p'
```

With `sed`'s `-z` option the input is processed as one large string and option `-n` only prints the matching parts (`/p`). 
Since the ip address is immediately followed by a newline and `;; Query time`, we can use a simpler regex to match the ip.
Both strings are captured in a group `(…)` and the input is replaced by `\1 \2` referring to these groups.